# How to split single tensor on multiple parameter servers in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, distributed

I am using Tensorflow, and I got a problem below:

There is one single huge tensor in my model, whose size is about 100 times larger than the others. I know that parameters are stored round robin, but my understanding is that single tensor belongs to single parameter server and this huge tensor can become a bottleneck.

Is it possible to split that huge tensor on multiple parameter servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that I can use a partitioner for tensorflow variables so that the tensor can be sharded on multiple parameter servers.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/state_ops#Variable_Partitioners_for_Sharding